# How to use relative path in Node Webkit

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit, nw.js

I can't use relative path using : `gui.Shell.openItem();`,
here is the code:

```
var gui = require('nw.gui');
gui.Shell.openItem('setup/BitTorrent.exe');
```

Comment: Try `'./setup/…'`? Relative to where?

Comment: thanks Bergi ,but It's not working , it's relative to a local file , at "setup" folder

Answer (score 0):

```
var path = require('path');
var absolutePath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'setup/BitTorrent.exe');
```